# Is there a string in Perl that is equal to all other strings under eq?

Tags: string, perl, equality, truthiness

I am running a string equality check like this:

```
if($myString eq "ExampleString")
```

Is there a value that `myString` could have which would cause execution to enter the `if` structure no matter what the string literal is?

Comment: Wouldn't that defeat the purpose of `eq`? Do you want such a value, or do you want to avoid such a value?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve? Your question is an example of what's known as X-Y problem: You're asking "how do I technically implement solution X to problem Y" instead of asking "What is the best way in Perl to solve problem Y", because X clearly sounds like the wrong solution to ANY problem :)

Comment: amon's answer is suitable for what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @zztops - amon's answer is technically great, but seems like a bad idea in larger scheme of things (e.g. I would strongly recommend that if you use something like that in a production code, you have somethnig wrong in your design). That's why I asked what problem you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: definitely not for production code...just screwing around

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, with objects and overloaded operators:

```
package AlwaysTrue {
  use overload 'eq' => sub { 1 },
               '""' => sub { ${+shift} };
  sub new {
    my ($class, $val) = @_;
    bless \$val => $class;
  }
}

my $foo = AlwaysTrue->new("foo");

say "foo is =$foo=";
say "foo eq bar" if $foo eq "bar";
```

Output:

```
foo is =foo=
foo eq bar
```

However, `"$foo" eq "bar"` is false, as this compares the underlying string.

Comment: I'm torn between +100 for a great hack and -100 for "WHYYYY would you ever want to do this???? This makes for amazingly unmaintainable code!"

Comment: @DVK Yeah, I myself was just staring at this post, thinking “What have I done?”. It is worth noting that this overloading violates the implied contract of the `eq` operator, e.g. it should be transitive: if `$a eq $b` and `$b eq $c` then `$a eq $c`, which doesn't hold for `$b->isa("AlwaysTrue")`.

Comment: +1 or -1 ? -1 for the scary code. +1 for answering the question. +1 to teach me something.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean "any string other than undef", then simply check

```
if (defined $myString)
```

If you mean "any string other than undef or empty string", then simply check

```
if ($myString) # Has a slight bug - will NOT enter if the number 0 passed
#or
if ($myString || $myString == 0)  # Avoids the above bug
```

If you mean ANY ANY string, you don't need an if.... but if you want one anyway:

```
if (1)
```

If you mean "any string that isn't looking like a number" (e.g. distinguish "11" from "11a"):

```
use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);
if (Scalar::Util::looks_like_number($myString))
```

Comment: is there a way to initialize a string to undef?

Comment: @zztops - `my $string = "a"; undef $string;` - but strictly speaking, it's not a "string" anymore. Perl does not have a "string type", just a scalar that contains a string and integer and floating components, just a variable that your code will TREAT as string

Comment: @DVK: simply leave the variable undefined: `my $string`.

Comment: @chepner - yes the end result is the same, but now there's nothing semantic to indicate it's a "string" (e.g. that it contained a string value). My example was illustrative, not "best technical"

Comment: Does it matter if it used to contain a string value? Undefined is undefined; there is no such thing as an "undefined string" or "undefined integer".

Comment: @chepner - technically, it doesn't matter at all. I explicitly stated so in my comment :) the strng assignment was there just to illustrate that a string can turn to undef.

Comment: `if ($myString || $myString == 0)` always matches, I believe you mean `if ($myString || $myString eq 0)`